# Starting Class from another Class with extra information android

Tags: android, class

I want to ask if it is possible to start one **non-activity Class** from another **non-activity Class**

I.e:

```
public class nubmerOne {
    String data = "send me please";
    public String getInfo(){

        if (/*something happens*/){
          //start Class numberTwo with some data
        }
    return "";
    }
}


public class numberTwo { //this class is started when condition in class One is true
String dataPlus = "";
    public String dosomething(){
       //started from class numberOne and get data

    dataPlus = data + "";  
    return dataPlus; 
    }
}
```

I know this is possible between BroadcastReceiver, Class that extends Activity and Service, bud it is possible to do it within two classes ?

Comment: What do you mean with *starting class*? There is a definition for Activity and Service but that is specific for them and won't work for other classes.

Comment: I ment to start all methods in class numberTwo, but its solved now thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but this looks like just classic Java.

Your first class must create the instance of the second class if the condition is satisfied and pass the data in the constructor of the second class.

```
public class nubmerOne {
    String data = "send me please";
    public String getInfo(){

        if (/*something happens*/){
          //start Class numberTwo with some data
          NumberTwo numberTwo = new NumberTwo (data);
          numberTwo.doSomething();
        }
    return "";
    }
}


public class NumberTwo { //this class is started when condition in class One is true
   private String data;

   public NumberTwo (String data){
      this.data = data;
   }
String dataPlus = "";
    public String dosomething(){
       //started from class numberOne and get data

    dataPlus = data + "";  
    return dataPlus; 
    }
}
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks works fine, I tried to do it with broadcast, but this is better.